# Is there a way to assign a value to variables each

Tags: r

Is there a way to assign a value to 2 variables. For example

```
q <- 3
q
[1] 3
```

But something like this

```
q , w <- 2  ## both q and w should hold value 2
q
[1] 3
w
[1] 3
```

Comment: Just `q <- w <- 3`

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the [zealott package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zeallot/index.html), which uses the `%<-%` operator allowing you to assign values to `q` and `w`.

```
library(zeallot)

c(q, w) %<-% rep(2, 2)

q
#[1] 2
w
#[1] 2
```

Another option is to use `purrr`:

```
purrr::walk2(c("q", "w"), 2, assign, envir = parent.frame())
```

This option can use just 1 number or if you do have a vector of values, then those could be provided as well:

```
purrr::walk2(c("q", "w"), c(2, 3), assign, envir = parent.frame())

q
#[1] 2
w
#[1] 3
```

Or the simplest (as shown by @DarrenTsai) if you only have 1 number is to use base R:

```
q <- w <- 2
```